# Selecting random words from article with php

Tags: php, random, article

I'd like to create a script for generating different content for my products.
For example, my first product content is:

> Acer 5520G Notebook using 15.6 LCD Panel.

Second one is;

> Acer 5720G Laptop using 15.6 Screen.

I want to create my articles like:

> Acer (5520G|5720G) (Laptop|Notebook) using 15.6 (LCD Panel|Screen)

And then, randomise all words written in (..) with php.

I did randomised words with;

```
$strings = '5520G, 5720G';
$key = array_rand($strings);
echo $strings[$key].
```

But I could'nt select (..) words from my articles, so any suggestions?

Comment: You're not initializing `$strings` as an array - try `$strings = array('5520G', '5720G');`

Comment: I think, could'nt explained myself. I want to select (.|.|.) words from my article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use JSON?

```
$items = json_decode('["Acer",["5520G","5720G"],["Laptop","Notebook"],"using 15.6",["LCD Panel","Screen"]]', true);

$out = array();
foreach($items as $item){
    if(is_array($item)){
        shuffle($item);
        $out[] = $item[0];
    }else{
        $out[] = $item;
    }
}

echo implode(' ', $out);
```

Comment: You are sir, you are perfect. But I've one question left; how can I replace my articles wich is like:
> Acer 5520G Notebook using 15.6 LCD Panel.
like this ?
> ["Acer",["5520G","5720G"],["Laptop","Notebook"],"using 15.6",["LCD Panel","Screen"]]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an array function on a string. Try this:

```
$strings = array('5520G', '5720G');
$key = array_rand($strings);
echo $strings[$key];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, your code working perfect. but my real question is getting this array from my article, I thought using Regex for this but could not do that.